# Losing state when changing widget (flipping credit card)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm working on a Credit Card animation for my application, when I insert the data from the front of the card, if I flip the card backwards, it loses the data it was on the front side. I'm working with a animation that sliding the card will make it turn.
[image: Backward]

[image: Front]

This is the code for the Card Tile:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/screens/checkout/card/card_back.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/screens/checkout/card/card_front.dart';

class CardTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardTileState createState() => _CardTileState();
}

class _CardTileState extends State<CardTile> {
  double horizontalDrag = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (horizontal) {
        setState(() {
          horizontalDrag += horizontal.delta.dx;
          horizontalDrag %= 360;
        });
      },
      child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.0001)
          ..rotateY(pi / 180 * horizontalDrag),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 10, 16, 16),
          width: 240,
          height: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.grey,
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color(0xff323232), Color(0xff000000)],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight)),
          child: horizontalDrag <= 90 || horizontalDrag >= 270
              ? CardFront()
              : Transform(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(pi),
                  child: CardBack(),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the CardFront:

```
import 'package:brasil_fields/brasil_fields.dart';
import 'package:credit_card_type_detector/credit_card_type_detector.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/screens/checkout/card/components/card_text_field.dart';
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

class CardFront extends StatelessWidget {
  final MaskTextInputFormatter dateFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(
      mask: '!# / ##', filter: {'#': RegExp('[0-9]'), '!': RegExp('[0-1]')});

  final MaskTextInputFormatter cardNumberFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(
      mask: '####  ####  ####  ####', filter: {'#': RegExp('[0-9]')});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Banco',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 10,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '|',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  letterSpacing: 10,
                  fontSize: 10,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                ' Seu cartão',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 10,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/chip.png',
            height: 35,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          CardTextField(25, "0000 0000 0000 0000", TextInputType.number,
              [cardNumberFormatter], TextAlign.start, (number) {
            if (number!.length != 22)
              return 'Inválido';
            else if (detectCCType(number) == CreditCardType.unknown)
              return 'Inválido';
            return null;
          }),
          Text(
            'Validade',
            style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11)),
          ),
          CardTextField(15, "00 / 00", TextInputType.number, [dateFormatter],
              TextAlign.start, (date) {
            if (date!.length != 7) return 'Inválido';
            return null;
          }),
          CardTextField(
              16, "Nome Completo", TextInputType.text, [], TextAlign.start,
              (name) {
            if (name!.isEmpty) return 'Inválido';
            return null;
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the CardBack:

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/screens/checkout/card/components/card_text_field.dart';
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

class CardBack extends StatelessWidget {
  final MaskTextInputFormatter securityFormatter =
      MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '###', filter: {'#': RegExp('[0-9]')});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.grey[700],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
            height: 40,
            width: 220,
            color: Colors.grey[700],
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                  child: CardTextField(15, '000', TextInputType.number,
                      [securityFormatter], TextAlign.end, (security) {}),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing setState, build method is being called and a new instance of your CardFront and CardBack is being created.

What you should do it, keep the data entered in the CardTile class and pass it when CardFront or CardBack is being built.

Something like

```
CardFront({String? name, String? cardNumber, String? month, String? year,
  StringCallback? onNameChange, StringCallback? onCardNumberChange, StringCallback? onMonthChange, StringCallback? onYearChange,});
}
```

Whenever there is value input into the fields, call the relavent callback method to let the CardTile know about the value and pass those value while CardFront or CardBack next time they are built.

Other solution would be to make your CardFront and CardBack stateful widgets with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.